# how to print awk output horizontal in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have script that greps some file and prints value , but it comes vertically like below

```
size=190000
date=1603278566981
repo-name=testupload
repo-path=/home/test/testupload
size=140000
date=1603278566981
repo-name=testupload2
repo-path=/home/test/testupload2
size=170000
date=1603278566981
repo-name=testupload3
repo-path=/home/test/testupload3
```

I want this should print as below

```
size    date            repo-name          repo-path
190000  1603278566981   testupload      /home/test/testupload
140000  1603278566981   testupload2     /home/test/testupload2
170000  1603278566981   testupload3     /home/test/testupload3
```

I tried things like below but it doesn't work

[image: awk]

anyway I can print it horizontal with formatted way like below

```
size    date            repo-name          repo-path
190000  1603278566981   testupload      /home/test/testupload
140000  1603278566981   testupload2     /home/test/testupload2
170000  1603278566981   testupload3     /home/test/testupload3
```

Please suggest and help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{ FS="=" }
/^size/{
  if(++count1==1){ header=$1 }
  sizeArr[++count]=$NF
  next
}
/^date/{
  if(++count2==1){ header=header OFS $1 }
  dateArr[count]=$NF
  next
}
/^repo-name/{
  if(++count3==1){ header=header OFS $1 }
  repoNameArr[count]=$NF
  next
}
/^repo-path/{
  if(++count4==1){ header=header OFS $1 }
  repopathArr[count]=$NF
  next
}
END{
  print header
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    printf("%s %s %s %s\n",sizeArr[i],dateArr[i],repoNameArr[i],repopathArr[i])
  }
}
' Input_file | column -t
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                        ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{ FS="=" }                              ##Starting BEGIN section from here and setting field separator as = here.
/^size/{                                     ##If line starts from size then do following.
  if(++count1==1){ header=$1 }               ##Checking if count1 variable is 1 then setting 1st field value as header.
  sizeArr[++count]=$NF                       ##Creating sizeArr with increasing count with 1 as an index and value is last field.
  next                                       ##next will skip all further statements.
}
/^date/{                                     ##If line starts from date then do
  if(++count2==1){ header=header OFS $1 }    ##Checking if count2 variable is 1 then setting 1st field value as header.
  dateArr[count]=$NF                         ##Creating dateArr with count as an index and value is last field.
  next                                       ##next will skip all further statements.
}
/^repo-name/{                                ##If line starts from repo-name then do
  if(++count3==1){ header=header OFS $1 }    ##Checking if count3 variable is 1 then setting 1st field value as header.
  repoNameArr[count]=$NF                     ##Creating repoNameArr with count as an index and value is last field.
  next                                       ##next will skip all further statements.
}
/^repo-path/{                                ##If line starts from repo-path then do
  if(++count4==1){ header=header OFS $1 }    ##Checking if count4 variable is 1 then setting 1st field value as header.
  repopathArr[count]=$NF                     ##Creating repopathArr with count as an index and value is last field.
  next                                       ##next will skip all further statements.
}
END{                                         ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  print header                               ##Printing header here.
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){                     ##Starting loop from 1 to value of count.
    printf("%s %s %s %s\n",sizeArr[i],dateArr[i],repoNameArr[i],repopathArr[i]) ##Printing all array values here with index as i here.
  }
}
' Input_file | column -t                     ##mentioning Input_file name and sendig awk output to column command for better looks.
```

Comment: Hello Ravinder,

just wanted to check if repo-name=(blank/null)  how I can pass it as zero 
zero=0 if [[ -z "$repo-name" ]] ; then repo-name="$zero"  will this add 0 where value is null or blank, I tried this but not working, if any of the variables has no value its should print zero , please guide

Comment: @Samurai, hello Samurai, kindly do open a new question, as one post one questions is encouraged l, thank you cheers 

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input field sequence is constant here's a version for mawk version 1.3.4:

```sh
awk -v RS='size=' -v OFS='\t' '
BEGIN{ fmt = "%s" OFS "%s" OFS "%s" OFS" %s" ORS }
function h(s) { return substr(s,1,index(s,"=")-1) }
function v(s) { return substr(s,1+index(s,"=")) }
NF{ if (!hdr++)
        printf(fmt,h(RS),h($2),h($3),h($4))
    printf(fmt,$1,v($2),v($3),v($4))
}
' data | column -t
```

... though it's safer to use `RS='(^|\n)size='` and edit first header attribute accordingly.

Output:

```
size    date           repo-name    repo-path
190000  1603278566981  testupload   /home/test/testupload
140000  1603278566981  testupload2  /home/test/testupload2
170000  1603278566981  testupload3  /home/test/testupload3
```